# Plot raw and predict values for 2x2x2 time-series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, factorial

This is the sample of my data

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

resource <- c("good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","bad","bad")

fertilizer <- c("none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen","none", "nitrogen","none","nitrogen")

t0 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t1 <-  sample(1:20, 16) 
t2 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t3 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t4 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t5 <-  sample(1:20, 16)
t6 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t7 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t8 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t9 <-  sample(10:100, 16)
t10 <-  sample(10:100, 16)

replicates <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

data <- data.frame(resource, fertilizer,replicates, t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10)

data$resource <- as.factor(data$resource)
data$fertilizer <- as.factor(data$fertilizer)

data.melt <- data %>% ungroup %>% gather(time, value, -replicates, -resource, -fertilizer)

data.melt$predict <- sample(1:200, 176)
```

Where, there are 2 factors for resources and fertilizer, so there are effectively 4 treatments and 4 x 4 = 16 replicates. Time is a factor with 10 levels. I ran a model, and predicted values which is in the `predict` column.

Now I want to plot a time-series with time on the x-axis and mean of the fitted value (predict) on and the raw values (value) on the y-axis, for each type of resource and fertilizer (4 treatments) [That is 4 plots]. I also want to add a confidence interval for the algal growth at each time point. Here is my attempt at the code.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=predicted)) + geom_point(size=3)+ stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean") + facet_grid(resource + fertilizer ~.)
```

With this simple code, I still get only 2 graphs and not 4. Also, the means of the predict function are not plotted. I don't know how to plot the `value` and `predicted` together, and the corresponding confidence intervals.

It would be helpful if anyone could also show how all four treatments can be on a single plot, and if I can get it to facet (like above)

Comment: Prior to downvoting please let me know what the trouble was?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but an example of what you want it to look like would help. Even hand-drawn, just so an answerer can be sure they're helping.

Comment: I have tried my best to explain it. Does that help?

Comment: I edited your code slightly, changing `data$nutrition` to `data$resource`. Please change it back or reject the edit if that is not correct.

Comment: Thanks. That looks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposed solution is to create a second data.frame containing all summary statistics such as mean predicted value. I show one way to do this with `group_by` and `summarize` from the `dplyr` package. The summary data needs to have columns `resource`, `fertilizer` and `time` that match the main data. The summary data also has columns with additional `y` values.

Then, the main data and the summary data need to be provided separately to the appropriate ggplot functions, but not in the main `ggplot()` call. `facet_grid` can be used to split the data into four plots.

```
# Convert time to factor, specifying correct order of time points.
data.melt$time = factor(data.melt$time, levels=paste("t", seq(0, 10), sep=""))

# Create an auxilliary data.frame containing summary data.
# I've used standard deviation as place-holder for confidence intervals;
# I'll let you calculate those on your own.
summary_dat = data.melt %>%
              group_by(resource, fertilizer, time) %>%
              summarise(mean_predicted=mean(predict),
                        upper_ci=mean(predict) + sd(predict),
                        lower_ci=mean(predict) - sd(predict))

p = ggplot() + 
    theme_bw() +
    geom_errorbar(data=summary_dat, aes(x=time, ymax=upper_ci, ymin=lower_ci),
                  width=0.3, size=0.7, colour="tomato") + 
    geom_point(data=data.melt, aes(x=time, y=value),
               size=1.6, colour="grey20", alpha=0.5) +
    geom_point(data=summary_dat, aes(x=time, y=mean_predicted),
               size=3, shape=21, fill="tomato", colour="grey20") +
    facet_grid(resource ~ fertilizer)

ggsave("plot.png", plot=p, height=4, width=6.5, units="in", dpi=150)
```

[image]

Comment: If I did not want to facet by fertilizer, and instead colour it in different colours how can i achieve this? Right now, after the aes in both geompoints function, i have added color = infection added. Wherever there is tomato I have added c("tomato","blue") and changed facet_grid(resources ~.) but I don't get a difference in plot. The facet_grid keeps popping up as an error

Comment: There is no column named `infection` in your example data. Also, assigning colors to factor levels doesn't work like that in ggplot; my example using "tomato" was setting a static color.

Comment: For your question about using color instead of faceting to distiguish different levels of `fertilizer`, see if this helps get you started: `ggplot() + geom_point(data=data.melt, aes(x=time, y=value, group=fertilizer), position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) + geom_errorbar(data=summary_dat, aes(x=time, ymax=upper_ci, ymin=lower_ci, group=fertilizer, color=fertilizer), position=position_dodge(width=0.5), width=0.5) + geom_point(data=summary_dat, aes(x=time, y=mean_predicted, group=fertilizer, color=fertilizer), size=3, position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) + facet_grid(resource ~ .)`

Comment: (1) Sorry for the typo in the comments (2) That helped a lot. Thanks!