# How to obtain length of column using dplyr when coding for confidence interval in R

Tags: r, dplyr, confidence-interval, sample-size

My data set can be referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745478/how-to-plot-raw-and-predict-values-for-2x2x2-time-series-in-r). In gist, I have a column called fitted for which I need to plot the mean and confidence intervals.

I am trying to code for confidence interval using dplyr function for my ggplot

```
data.melt$time = factor(data.melt$time, levels=paste("t", seq(0, 10), sep=""))
```

Here is the code

```
summary_dat = data.melt$time  %>%
              group_by(resource, fertilizer, time) %>%
              summarise(mean_predict=mean(fitted),
                        sd_predict = sd(fitted),
                        n_predict = n(fitted)) %>%

  mutate(se = sd_predict / sqrt(n_predict),
         lower_ci = mean_predict - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n_predict - 1) * se_predict,
         upper_ci = mean_predict + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n_predict - 1) * se_predict)
```

However, R does not allow me to code n_predict as n(fitted). I also tried length(fitted) but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Your approach should work if you use `length()` and not `n()`, but your code has a bunch of small typos. The first line should begin with the entire data frame `data.melt`, not `data.melt$time`, the column in question is called `predict`, not `fitted`, and the standard error is referred to by two different names, `se` and `se_predict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convenience function `n()` in `dplyr` only counts the number of rows in the subset, rather than the length of one of the columns in the subset. It does not take arguments. You want to use either `n_predict = n()` or `n_predict = length(predict)`.